# Prevent multiple instances of flutter desktop app when using uni_links_desktop

Tags: flutter, windows, deep-linking

I have a flutter windows app built that uses [uni_links_desktop](https://pub.dev/packages/uni_links_desktop). The app launches when a relevant protocol is loaded. However, it creates a new instance of itself everytime I click a different resource. it almost looks like it only reads the initial url only

I have tried the following so far:

1. Modify the `cpp` file to relect my app name as specified in `pubspec.yaml`

```cpp
 HWND hwnd = ::FindWindow(L"FLUTTER_RUNNER_WIN32_WINDOW", L"app"); // change from default uni_links_desktop_example
```

I have also tried copying what the example app from unilinks has into my main.dart file. The same results persists. Just in case, I also modified my `AndroidManifest.xml` to have the below:

```xml
  <activity
      android:name=".MainActivity"
      android:exported="true"
      android:launchMode="singleTask" # have one instance of the app
```

The above measures stil do not work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this was relatively simple and an oversight on my end. The error occurs because of the following:
My `main.cpp` has the below which is necessary from the library docs.

```cpp
HWND hwnd = ::FindWindow(L"FLUTTER_RUNNER_WIN32_WINDOW", L"app name");
```

However, I overrode this on creating my window and configuring the size in `window.Create`

```cpp
if (!window.Create(L"random name", origin, size))
```

The right approach is to make sure that the labels match.